# Restructuring my code to avoid async .getJSON AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-maps, asynchronous

I trying to implement the Google Maps v3 API on my website. I am currently using a JS script to load the map. Currently, all the values for center, zoom, and some other stuff are hard coded into my script. I would like to be able to pull those values from a PHP file in JSON form. In my current script file, I call my functions in this order:

```
function initJSON(){
    var answerjson = undefined;
    var requestAnswer = $.getJSON('URL');
    requestAnswer.done(function (data) {
    answerjson = data;
    }); 
}

function initMap() {

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: //Would like to get data from JSON,
    center: //Would like to get data from JSON,
    mapTypeId: 'terrain'
    });

    //Code here about creating a shape outliner, not important

    variableDefinedAbove.addListener('click', showArrays);

}


function showArrays(event) {
    var vertices = this.getPath();
    var contentString = //Would like to get data from JSON ;        
    infoWindow.setContent(contentString);
    infoWindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
    infoWindow.open(map);
}
```

When I call this script, Javascript completes the initMap() and showArrays() functions before initJSON can pull the data. I understand how to put data from the completed initJSON() into my other functions, but 'answerjson' is undefined when those functions run, making them useless. Is there a way I can restructure my program so that initJSON() has to complete before any other functions are run? I know I could probably do this with async and Promises, but I have no experience with them, and I'd rather use them if there is a simpler solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is to call your functions from the `.done` of your `getJSON` call - like so:

```
function initJSON(){
    //var answerjson = undefined; dont do this, you can pass this to where you need it
    var requestAnswer = $.getJSON('URL');
    requestAnswer.done(function (data) {
        //answerjson = data;
        //call your function here
        initMap(data); //pass data to map function
    }); 
}
```

And update your `initMap` function to take your data from the server:

```
function initMap(data) {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: data.someProperty,//replace with actual prop name
        center: data.someOtherProperty, //replace with actual prop name
        mapTypeId: 'terrain'
    });

    //Code here about creating a shape outliner, not important

    variableDefinedAbove.addListener('click', showArrays);
}
```

Comment: Is there a way I can print out the value of data initMap() receives to verify it is working correctly? Right now I put var abc = data; and console.log(abc); at the top of initMap() and it still returns undefined. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: @user1234231 - Nope, that should work. Can you verify that the `data` coming back from your server is the actual data you expect? Pop open your console, head to the "network" tab and inspect your AJAX call (specifically the response)

Comment: Ok, I was able to narrow it down to the initial initJSON() function is never called at all. Thanks.